# C++ Parsing string to find occurrence

Tags: c++, string, parsing, input, substring

So I need to parse the input of the user in the following way: 
If the user enters

```
C:\Program\Folder\NextFolder\File.txt
```

OR

```
C:\Program\Folder\NextFolder\File.txt\
```

Then I want to remove the file and just save

```
C:\Program\Folder\NextFolder\
```

I essentially want to find the first occurrence of `\` starting at the end and if they put a trailing slash then I can find the second occurrence. I can decifer first or second with this code:

```
input.substr(input.size()-1,1)!="/"
```

But I don't understand how to find the first occurrence *starting* from the end. Any ideas?

Comment: C:\Program\Folder\NextFolder\File.txt\ is not file, this is directory!

Answer (score 1):

This

```
input.substr(input.size()-1,1)!="/"
```

is very inefficient*. Use:

```
if( ! input.empty() && input[ input.length() - 1 ] == '/' )
{
    // something
}
```

---

Finding the first occurrence of something, starting from the end is the same as finding the last "something", starting from the beginning. You may use [`find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/), or [`rfind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/) Or, you may even use standard `find`, combined with [`rbegin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/) and [`rend`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rend/)

---

*`std::string::substr` creates one substring, `"/"` probably creates another (depends on `std::string::operator!=`), compares the two strings and destroys the temp objects.

---

Note that

> C:\Program\Folder\NextFolder\File.txt\

is not a path to a file, it's a directory.

Answer (score 1):

If your `input` is of type `std::string`( that I think it is ) you can search it using `string::find` for normal search and `string::rfind` for reverse search( end to start ) and also to check last character you don't need and you shouldn't use `substr`, since it create a new instance of string just to check one character. You may just say `if( input.back() == '/' )`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ strings, then try the [reverse iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rend/) on the strings, to write your own logic on what is acceptable and what is not. There is a clear example in the link I provided.

From what I guessed, you are trying to store the directory name given a path which could be end with a file or a directory.

If that is the case, you are better of removing the trailing '\' and checking if it is a directory, and stop if it is, or else proceed if it is not.

Alternately, you can try splitting the string on '\' into two parts. Some related notes [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

If those are actual file names, (looks like you are using windows), so try the [_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function as well.